# How to assign syslog facility of Tor?

Tags: configuration, socks, torsocks, log

I'm running Tor as a daemon and enabled the syslog. The Tor daemon is running well as a socks proxy server and sending all logs to /var/log/messages.

But I want to make Tor to write the log through syslog to one of the local[0-7] syslog facility, then I can clearly read the Tor specific logs in a single log file, for example /var/log/torlog.

It seems there is no way to assign the syslog facility. Does anyone know how to assign syslog facility ?

Comment: If you want it to log to a file, surely you'd want to use the `file` log facility, rather than `syslog`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to assign the syslog facility. A not working work around suggests to use `Log info file /var/log/torlog` , however this work around is really not working because Tor isn't run by root or privileged user.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `file` option for `Log` to make Tor log to a specific file.

For example by setting the Log line in your `torrc` to this:

`Log info file /var/log/torlog`

Comment: I did consider this option, but it won't go /var/log directory because Tor is not run as root.

Comment: You could always change the permission on the directory...

Comment: I think rare people like to change the permission of the system directory `/var/log`. There is also the security concern.

Comment: That is how the Tor projects own debian package handles it. I don't think it's much of a security concern if done properly.

Comment: I agree. But I don't know how to change the permission of `/var/log` properly without impact the security. Maybe it needs a specific directory instead of `/var/log` for this workaround to work. Currently, I don't want a specific directory. How about Tor add a function to assign the syslog facility ?

Comment: Create a folder called `tor` under `/var/log` that is owned and only writable/readable by the user the tor process runs under?

Comment: Yeah, I know what you are talking about. But the log file would be `/var/log/tor/torlog`. 1) The log file isn't in `/var/log`; 2) Tor seems have no logrotate mechanism. Thus, I hope Tor can let user to customize the syslog facility.

Comment: Uh...most services don't have their own log rotate system, most are managed by the operating system. If you SIGHUP tor it will "reload its configuration (including closing and reopening logs)" which is what logrotate daemons do to rotate log files.